# Как скомпилировать или сделать вручную aar имея лишь Android смартфон?

Tags: android, android-library

Здравствуйте, пишу код в AIDE, не смог разобраться как сделать библиотеку и выложить ее в maven, решил, что она будет в формате `aar` и подключаться добавлением в папку `libs`. Каким образом можно собрать `aar` без компьютера? И еще - куда бы лучше ее загрузить, чтобы можно было скачать по ссылке в README.md?

Comment: без компа никак

Comment: @pavel163 а что мешает?

Comment: @D-side у вас на телефоне есть компилятор

Comment: @pavel163 на планшете есть. Посмотрите, что такое AIDE.

Comment: @D-side Спасибо, не знал, что есть такая тулза.

Comment: @D-side, я вот не пойму как аар собрать в аиде

Comment: @Flippy я тоже не знаю, не разбирал процессы сборки. Мне было интересно, почему Павел убеждён в невозможности этого. Больше он не убеждён :)